# Autoload Composer

Tags: php, composer

При переносе проекта с локального компьютера на сервер не работает автозагрузка  класса Routing. Ошибка :Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'routing\Routing' not found
Структура проекта:

```
[ - domain
    - public
        -test.php
    - routing
        -routing.php
    - vendor
    - composer.json
]
```

composer.json -

```
{
"require": {
    "telegram-bot/api": "^2.3"
},

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "routing\\": "routing/"
    }
}}
```

public/test.php

```
    <?php
require_once'../vendor/autoload.php';
new routing\Routing('Foo','Bar');
```

routing/routing.php

```
<?php
namespace routing;

class Routing{
    public $chat_bot_type;
    public $token;
    public function __construct($chat_bot_type,$token)
    {
        $this->chat_bot_type = $chat_bot_type;
        $this->token = $token;

    }
```

Домашний сервер OpenServer php 7.2
Удаленный хостинг Ubuntu 18.04 php 7.2

Comment: Какую конкретно ошибку Вы получаете ?

Comment: @KirillBabinec, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'routing\Routing' not found

Comment: Делали ли вы composer dump-autoload на удаленке ?

Comment: @KirillBabinec , да( Generating autoload files) , composer install(
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files)

Answer (score 0):

Класс с заглавной буквы а название файла нет , из за это проблема с автозагрузкой psr-4. Решение переименовать файл routing.php to Routing.php.